# Ubuntu freezes/crashes

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, freeze, crash

[EDIT] I may need to be more specific with the problem and add some informations, I just don't know what, if you can help me and need anything to know just tell me and I add asap, ty.

I have a Acer laptop with a preinstalled Windows 10, and since I got into programming I decided to set up a dual boot with Ubuntu.

I had some trouble doing this and I found I needed to update BIOS and it solved my problem. I think it's worth mentioning this laptop has only an SSD 250gb as storage and I gave the Linux partition 100gb.

The problem comes here, Ubuntu is working fine, but when I use specific programs, such as Bluej IDE or even Firefox, after a short time everything freezes (even mouse). Sometimes after some minutes the program crashses and  the pc goes back to working fine, sometimes instead I have to hard shutdown the pc to restart it.

I have no clue why it is acting this way, hopefully someone can help, thanks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and kernel do you use? Maybe this issue could be resolved by kernel upgrading or by manipulation with drivers. Also, you could try to launch Firefox from terminal by typing `firefox`. It could give log that could be useful in bug inspecting.

Comment: I'm currently using "5.3.0-26-generic #28~18.04.1-Ubuntu" as kernel version and ubuntu version. Also, I can run firefox from terminal but how do I see the logs? Thanks btw

Comment: Logs are displayed in terminal when you launch Firefox from it. In my case Firefox starts successfully from terminal despite a lot of `Theme parsing error` Gtk-WARNING messages. In your case you could see something else, that causes its unstable processing.

Comment: So, when starting firefox from terminal it doesn't give me any error whatsoever, also I should mention it happened really rarely that firefox crashed, maybe only when I had many tabs open. The big problem I have is with bluej, I know there are way better IDE but that is what my school uses and what I will have to use during exam sessions. Starting bluej from terminal gives me this warning: "(java:2808): Gdk-WARNING **: 14:14:13.848: XSetErrorHandler() called with a GDK error trap pushed. Don't do that.". 10 minutes or so into programming with it crashes everytime.

Comment: One more thing I wanna say is that it is strange that firefox doesn't tell me anything, I remember I tried to open firefox from terminal before and it used to give a warning, now that I re-tried it doesn't say anything. In fact lately I had no problems with firefox.

Comment: I see, that Bluej 4.2.2 released 4 October 2019 requires Ubuntu 18.10 or later. But you have the same kernel as I have with my 19.10. I've installed Bluj and ran it with the same warning, but it works without issues for me. You could try to upgrade your system to 19.10 also. Is your project you're working with big?

Comment: No, I would definitely not could it big, usually are small project composed of 4/5 classes/interfaces... At max I can recall having 15 files inside a project but yet nothing too complex. The crashes that makes my laptop freeze occure when I'm actually typing code, all start going slowly and eventually everything stops, even mouse. I guess I should try to upgrade my system. I've also been advised to change my OS completely to a fedora or mint, which should be lighter.

Answer (score 1):

The answers in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/4408) over at Ask Ubuntu should cover you.

> ### When the mouse stops working:
>
> If the keyboard still works, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and
>   run `gnome-terminal` (or, if these fail to launch, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and login with your *username* and *password*). From there you can troubleshoot things. I'm not going to get into mouse troubleshooting here, as I haven't researched it. If you just want to try restarting the GUI, run `sudo service lightdm restart`. This should bring down the GUI, which will then attempt to respawn, bringing you back to the login screen.

---

If you dn't have <kbd>SysReq (Print Screen)</kbd> on your keyboard check [here](https://superuser.com/q/562348) or search online with your specific model number.

> If it locks up completely, you can REISUB it, which is a safer
>   alternative to just cold rebooting the computer.
>
> REISUB by:
>
> While holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the <kbd>SysReq (Print Screen)</kbd>
>   keys, type
>   <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.
>
> ```
> R:  Switch to XLATE mode
> E:  Send Terminate signal to all processes except for init
> I:  Send Kill signal to all processes except for init
> S:  Sync all mounted file-systems
> U:  Remount file-systems as read-only
> B:  Reboot
> ```
>
> REISUB is BUSIER backwards, as in "The System is **busier** than it
>   should be", if you need to remember it.  Or mnemonically - **R**eboot;
>   **E**ven; **I**f; **S**ystem; **U**tterly; **B**roken.
>
> This is the SysReq key:
>
> [image: SysReq key]
>
> **NOTE:** There exists less radical way than rebooting the whole system. If <kbd>SysReq</kbd> key works, you can kill processes
>   one-by-one using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. Kernel
>   will kill the mostly «expensive» process each time. If you want to
>   kill all processes for one console, you can issue
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
>
> **NOTE:** You should explicitly enable these key combinations. Ubuntu ships with sysrq default setting 176 (128+32+16), which allows to run
>   only **SUB** part of REISUB combination. You can change it to 1 or,
>   which is potentially less harmful, 244. To do this:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf
> ```
>
> and switch 176 to 244; then
>
> ```
> echo 244 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
> ```
>
> It will immediately work! You can test this by pressing
>   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. For me, it killed
>   active browser tab, then all extensions. And if you will continue, you
>   can reach X Server restart.
>
> More info on all the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd> functions
>   [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key).